# Gremlin- how to find paths from A to Z that went through G only

Tags: graph-theory, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Need some help with Gremlin:  If I know the start vertex and the end vertex and there are multiple paths between start and end BUT I have a couple of vertexes along the way.  How can I find the correct path based on the data I have?

For instance here I what I have to find the paths from 'college' to 'finch'

```
g.V().has('station','college').
       repeat(out().simplePath())
        .until(has('station','finch'))
        .path().by('station')
```

**Results**

```
==>[college, wellesley, bloor-yonge, rosedale, summerhill, st. clair, davisville, eglinton, lawrence, york mills, sheppard-yonge, north york centre, finch]
==>[college, dundas, queen, king, union, st. andrew, osgoode, st. patrick, queenspark, museum, st. george, bay, bloor-yonge, rosedale, summerhill, st. clair, davisville, eglinton, lawrence, york mills, sheppard-yonge, north york centre, finch]
```

But how to i get the correct path that went THROUGH 'dundas' for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a path-bound counter that you only increment if you find a certain element along the path:

```
g.withSack(0).V().has('station','college').
  repeat(out().simplePath().
         choose(has('station','dundas'),
                  sack(sum).by(constant(1)))).
    until(has('station','finch')).
  filter(sack().is(1)).
  path().
    by('station')
```

Adding more necessary points (e.g. filter paths that go through `G`, `H` and `P`) is easy with this approach.

However, if it's only one vertex that has to be part of the path, then sel-fish's answer is another valid option (don't know why it got downvoted).

Comment: Hey Daniel, this is immensely helpful and is working great so far.  Quick question before I accept- you mentioned it's easy to include other stations as requirements the path must have gone through (G, H, P).  How can I include multiple intermediate steps?

Comment: You just add 1 to the sack value each time you see one of the expected vertices. `simplePath()` ensures that you every vertex only once, so having a sack value of 3, in the end, means that you found all 3 vertices along the path.

Answer (score -1):

**Daniel Kuppitz's answer is much better than mine.**

```
g.V().has('station','college').
    repeat(out().simplePath()).
        until(has('station','finch')).
    path().
    where(unfold().has('station', 'dundas')).
    unfold().values('station').fold()
```